# Enter multiple values in mysql row separate by comma output one by one using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I want to Enter multiple values in MySql database row separate by comma and show users in drop-down list using Codeigniter.

for-example a shopping site product have various values like product (color: Red,White,Blue,Orange) theses different values store in one row and show these values to user in drop-down list.

My current list show as:
[image]

Here is my code:
**Model**

```
public function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_products')
                 ->order_by(1,'DESC');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        $query = $data->result_array();

        foreach ($query as $result) {

            if ($result['color_values']) {
                $result['color_values'] = explode(',' , $result['color_values']);
            }
            if ($result['size_values']) {
                $result['size_values'] = explode(',',$result['size_values']);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('cartm');
        $data['posts'] = $this->cartm->get_all();
        $this->load->view('cart/index',$data);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
            <li>
                <form method="post" action="<?=base_url();?>cart_test/add/">

                    <p><?=$post['pro_name'];?></p>

                    <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px" src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$post['prod_image'];?>">

                    <p>$<?=$post['prod_price'];?></p>

                    <?php if($post['color_values']) : ?>
                        <p>Color: <select>
                            <option><?=$post['color_values']?></option>
                        </select></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($post['size_values']) : ?>
                        <p>Size: <select>
                            <option><?=$post['size_values'];?></option>
                        </select></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </form>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: to combine values in mysql SELECT use CONCAT(val1,val2...), also check docs for CONCAT_WS()

Comment: Where are the product options comming from? A seperate table?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to create a view that would look something like this :

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.pro_name, p.prod_image, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(opt_color.option_value_id, '::', opt_color.option_value_name) SEPARATOR '||') AS color_options
    FROM vendor_products AS p
    LEFT JOIN vendor_products_options AS opt_color ON p.prod_id = opt_color .prod_id AND opt_color .option_id = 1
    GROUP BY p.prod_id
    -- Other joins for other options varying the option_id
```

See reference for group_concat() function here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

You then use the view for your model instead of the table itself. The code to extract the options would look like this :

```
    foreach ($query as $result) {
        if (!empty($result['color_options'])) {
            $result['color_options'] = explode('||', $result['color_options']);
        }
    }
```

And the code to generate the HTML for the select in your view :

```
<?php if($post['color_options']) : ?>
    <p>Color: 
    <select>
        <?php
        foreach($post['color_options'] as $optValue) {
            $option_array = explode('::', $optValue);
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$option_array[0]?>"><?=$option_array[1]?></option>
        <?php
        foreach() {
        ?>
    </select>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i write same code but find error in view this code: (<option value="<?=$option_array[0]"><?=$option_array[1]?></option>)

show Error undefined offset 1

Comment: There was a missing ?> after $option_array[0]

Comment: i remove this mistake but nothing show in dropdown select list

Comment: do you have anything in the vendor_products_options  table?